# laravel hasMany polymorphic relationship in where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to select the picture with the most likes within a specific category from my database. I have a database table storing the pictures and a table storing the likes. The pictures table is related to likeable table through a hasMany polymorphic relationship.

Like model:

```
    public function likeable() 
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Picture model:

```
 public function likes()
 {
     return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
 }
```

Home Controller:

```
Picture::where('picture_type', 'food')->orderBy(likes(), 'desc')->first();
```

Likeable Migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likeable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('likeable_id');
        $table->string('likeable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

So far, the above line of code, in my home controller returns an error. From what I understand, the likes method has to be called on a specific instance. However, I do not know how to implement this all the while keeping my where clause.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are wanting to order pictures by the most likes.

In which case, you want something like this:

```
Picture::withCount('likes')->where('picture_type', 'food')->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: Yes, except I cannot simply get the like count for pictures as one column can store likes for both comments and pictures.

Comment: Doesn't your likes relationship take care of scoping the query to the correct model and ID?

Comment: Yes it does. Your solution fixed my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem @ZionComer